# Input filed is not working properly in place of ngFor

Tags: angular

Values entered by the user inside a given input field shows only one letter. Can anyone please help.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8kpyxt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Probably if you use reactive form in this case, issue will resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **trackBy**

> The trackBy function takes the index and the current item as arguments
>   and needs to return the unique identifier for this item

**component.html**

```
<div class="form-group" *ngFor="let Type of type.headings;trackBy: cmpare;let i=index">
<label>Heading{{i+1}}</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" [name]="'name1_'+i" [(ngModel)]="type.headings[i]">
</div>
```

**component.ts**

```
cmpare(index) {
  return index;
}
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uwfphr
Ref:https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#change-propagation